# Numpy - create an almost zero matrix with row from other matrix

Tags: python, performance, numpy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have square matrix **A** and I want to create matrix **Z** which elements are zero everywhere except for an i'th row, and the i'th row is j'th row of matrix **A**.

I am aware of two ways to accomplish this. The fist one is fairly straightforward and seems to be the most effective performance-wise:

```
def do_this(mx: np.array, i: int, j: int):
    Z = np.zeros_like(mx)
    Z[i, :] = mx[j, :]
    return Z
```

The other, less straightforward way and seemingly much less efficient, is to prepare a **mx** matrix beforehand, which a zero matrix of the same shape as **A**, but has 1 in it's (i, j) position, and then to calculate **Z** as **mx** @ **A**.

```
def do_this_other_way(mx: np.array, ref_mx: np.array):
    return ref_mx @ mx
```

I decided to benchmark both approaches:

```
from time import time
import numpy as np

n = 20
num_iters = 5000
A = np.random.rand(n, n)
i, j = 5, 10

t = time()
for _ in range(num_iters):
    Z = do_this(A, i, j)
print((time() - t) / num_iters)

ref_mx = np.zeros_like(A)
ref_mx[i, j] = 1
t = time()
for _ in range(num_iters):
    Z = do_this_other_way(A, ref_mx)
print((time() - t) / num_iters)
```

However, when **A** is relatively small (on my laptop it means that **A**'s size is less than 40), **do_this_other_way** wins, and when **A** has size like 20, it wins by an order of magnitude. 
That's it: I have doubts that I am doing it the most effective way possible in numpy. Is it possible to do it better without resorting to writing your own low-level implementation of **do_this**?

Comment: What is your _question_? (Also, do not use `time` for timing.)

Comment: "Is it possible to do it better without resorting to writing your own low-level implementation of **do_this**?"